# Firebase fetch taking too long

Tags: reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get some user data from my firebase (Realtime Database), but my code runs before the data has been "fetched", so when I try to use the variable in my React code I just get undefined instead of the value in the database.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: That said: you can make something that is asynchronous work synchronously, or hope for it to not take too long. You'll instead have to accept that is takes however long it takes, and use the correct method of dealing with asynchronous APIs. That could be: 1) putting all code that needs the data in the callback, 2) handling the Promise that is returned by many asynchronous APIs and hooking into the `then` callback, 3) using `await` to make this more readable. For more on these, see https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-realtime-database%5d%5bjavascript%5d%20asynchronous